# Directional derivative for function involving summation of absolute value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, subgradient

> Calculate the directional derivative for the function
>
> $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} |x_{i+1} - x_i|$$
>
> where $\textbf{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)^T$, with $n \geq 2$ for any vector $\textbf{v}=(v_1,...,v_n)^T$.

What I thought was, we might have to erase the absolute value first. Without absolute values some terms could be easily eliminated. But don't know how to achieve such goal. Could anyone shed light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the limit definition of the directional derivative.

$$\nabla_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|(x_{i+1}+hv_{i+1})-(x_i+hv_i)|-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|x_{i+1}-x_i|}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|(x_{i+1}-x_i)+h(v_{i+1}-v_i)|-|x_{i+1}-x_i|}{h}$$

Here we can use the fact that $|a|>|b|\implies|a+b|=|a|+b\ sgn(a)$, where sgn signifies the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). This will only work when $x_{i+1}-x_i\neq0$.

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(v_{i+1}-v_i)sgn(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$

The limit will not converge to this sum if and only if there is at least one $i$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i=0$ and $v_{i+1}-v{i}\neq 0$. If such an i exists, there will be a term $|v_{i+1}-v_i|\frac{|h|}{h}$, which does not have a limit as $h\to 0$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the prompt reply, Kajelad. Referring the case $x_{i+1}-x_i=0$, do you think it could be represented by $|v_{i+1}-v_i|$? Because $sgn(x)=0$ when $x=0$, which indicates we have to rewrite the condition for $sgn(0)$.

Comment: @GabrielChu:  Not necessarily. The trouble is that the limit will not necessarily converge since the term in the sum will be $|v_{i-1}-v_i|\frac{|h|}{h}$, which has a discontinuity at $h=0$. If there are multiple such terms, though, they may cancel and cause the limit to converge. I'm not entirely sure how to account for all of these possibilities.

Comment: Actually, because $|v_{i-1}-v{i}|\frac{|h|}{h}$ is nonnegative when h>0 and nonpositive when h<0, the limit will not exist if there is at least one $i$ such that $x_{i+1}-x{i}=0$ and $v_{i+1}-v{i}\neq 0$ Otherwise it will converge to the sum given.